# Nodejs http request NULL due to non-blocking nature

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

//Handling get request from the client

```
app.get('/watch', function(req, res) {
    //A for loop goes here which makes multiple requests to an external API and stores the result in a variable data
    console.log(data); //Gives an empty value!!
    res.write(data); //Sends an empty value
}
```

Now when I try to log the data variable DURING the loop, it's value is as expected. However it sends data as an empty variable to the client. I am pretty sure this is because the for loop takes a while to execute and Node being non-blocking moves to the next part of the code. Is there a workaround for this or is something fundamentally wrong with the design of my code?

EDIT: Posting the for loop as requested

```
for(var num in data.items)
    {
        url ='/Product';
        options={
            host:"api.xyz.com",
            path:url
        };

        http.get(options,function(response){
            var responseData = "";
            response.setEncoding('utf8');
            //stream the data into the response
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                responseData+=chunk.toString();
            });
            //responseData=JSON.parse(responseData);
            //write the data at the end
            response.on('end', function(){

                body=JSON.parse(responseData);
                var discount=body.product[0].styles[0].percentOff.replace('%','');

                if(discount>=20)
                {
                    discounted_json.disc_items.push({"percentOff":discount});
                }

            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: You should put the `res.write()` in the data gathering loop callback as well.

Comment: It gives me a "Header already sent error" and rightly so

Comment: Maybe you can post some simplified version of your data gathering loop as well. There should be some callback in there, which is important.

Comment: Step 1: Use https://github.com/mikeal/request

Comment: @UdaiArora So from a quick glance, the `res.write()` call should be *after*  the ` if(discount>=20)` clause in the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to call multiple asynchronous functions in order, you should call the first one, call the next one in it's callback and so on. The code would look like:

```
asyncFunction1(args, function () {
  asyncFunction2(args, function () {
    asyncFunction3(args, function () {
      // ...
    })
  })
});
```

Using this approach, you may end up with an ugly hard-to-maintain piece of code.

There are various ways to achieve the same functionality without nesting callbacks, like using [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [node-fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers).

Comment: I wouldn't have minded nesting as it's just 2 functions which are to be called. How would this be applied to my case is what I am asking.